# Getting issue when auth attempt used

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I really try to debug my issues on my own before I bring them here, but I seriously cannot find a solution to my laravel auth problem, though it seems to be a common issue.

My authentication will not login. It always returns false and I don't understand why.

I am trying to login using auth:attempt but its not working . Going always in else condition.

When auth attempt getting success its automatically going in if condition otherwise other condition

```
    <?php

           namespace App\Http\Controllers;

           use Illuminate\Http\Request;
           use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
           use App\Http\Controllers\Redirect;
           use App\User;
           use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



          class AdminCreateLogin extends Controller
         {
            public function addAdmin(Request $request)
            { 
                $name = $request->username;
                $password = $request->password;
                $password = Hash::make($password);
                 $email = $request->email;

                   
           $user= new User;

           $user->name = $name;
           $user->password = $password;
           $user->email = $email;

            $user->save();
    
        }
        public function adminLogin(Request $request)
        {
           $email = $request->email;
           $password1 = $request->password;
           $password = bcrypt($password1);
           //$password = hash:make($password1);
           $userdata = array(
                                'email' => $email,
                                'password' => $password
                        );
           if(Auth::attempt($userdata))
           {
                 echo "login";
                die;
                return redirect('/admin/post/list');    
            }
            else
            {
                   echo "login not";
                   die;
                   return back()->with('error',"Invalid Login");
            }

       }
        }
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: `Auth::attempt()` need raw password so no need to  `bcrypt ()` it

Comment: the plain text password is what is passed to `attempt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `bcrypt` manually. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```